# как распаралелить выполнение однотипных задач в Android по типу Fork/Join?

Tags: android

В фрагменте я загружаю Drawable из внешнего источника (от 18 до 32 штук).
Сначала делал эту задачу в одном рабочем потоке, через AsyncTask (долго...). Хотел распараллелить, но оказалось что RecursiveTask поддерживается только с API 21 и выше (мой проект стартует с API 16). Можно, конечно запустить ряд AsyncTask, но не нашел способ дождаться выполнения всех в определенной точке (да и есть ли он?). Можно, конечно, попробовать нагородить средствами java (запустить несколько потоков в моем рабочем потоке AsyncTask и дожидаться через join()). Или есть еще какой способ, не городить костыли?

Comment: ознакомтесь с ExecutorService  https://habrahabr.ru/post/116363/

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, пригодилось!

Comment: это не может не радовать, обращайтесь =)